# SimpleCov Rails test coverage changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simplecov

I'm using SimpleCov with my rails app. Everything is working, but there seems to be a bug or i'm doing something wrong.

My test coverage when I run `rake test` comes back at 90.77%.

Then `rake test TEST=test/path/to/file_test` which returns 66%.

Finally, `rake test` and the coverage returned is 66%.

Is there some caching issue i'm missing? Also, I've notice all the sudden on the low 66% it seems to be counting all the blank lines as failed(see img).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by this bug at the merge process: https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/444. The suggested workaround worked for me:

At `lib/simplecov/merge_helpers.rb` replace `if element.nil? && new_array[i].nil?` with `if element.nil? || new_array[i].nil?`

All credit goes to [ksmurphy](https://github.com/ksmurphy).